# Laravel Packages Route

Tags: php, laravel, package, laravel-middleware

i made some laravel packages, the packages work well if user is not log in, but when user has login and visiting route from packages laravel consider that the user has not log in yet, i ensure that user has successfully log in, because another menu/route not come from the packages it work well. what wrong here ? is i am missing something ?

here is my controller

```
namespace Offices\Referensi;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class ReferensiController extends Controller
{

    function tes()
    {
        echo "Halo";
    }
}
```

here is my service provider

```
class ReferensiServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{

    public function boot()
    {
        include __DIR__.'/routes.php';
    }

    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->make('Offices\Referensi\ReferensiController');
    }
}
```

and here is the routes.php

```
<?php
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function() {
    Route::get('referensi/area','Offices\Referensi\ReferensiController@tes');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

never mind, i know the problem, i just missing the web middleware on the route file, so the routes.php should be

```
<?php
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web','auth']], function() {
    Route::get('referensi/area','Offices\Referensi\ReferensiController@tes');
});
```